# RAILS : Read_only field using rendered form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form view with an email text field and some other type of field in a view named _form.html.haml, as follows :

```
....
= easy_form_for @form, label_col: 'col-md-2', control_col: 'col-md-10' do |f|

    = f.text_field :name,  required: true
    = f.text_field :email, required: true
    = f.text_area  :description, rows: 5
....
```

And an edit.html.haml view that inherits from this form as follows:

```
...
%h2.page-header= page_title

= render 'form'
...
```

I would like to make a Patch on this form in the edit.html.haml view just gray the email field and leave the other fields of the form as they are

Answer (score 0):

You could send a parameter to the `form` partial and handle the readonly part there.

```
= render partial: 'form', locals: { disable_email: true }
```

If the `form` partial does not receive any `disable_email` it will default to `false`.

```
....
- disable_email = local_assigns.has_key?(:disable_email) ? disable_email : false
= easy_form_for @form, label_col: 'col-md-2', control_col: 'col-md-10' do |f|

  = f.text_field :name,  required: true
  = f.text_field :email, required: true, readonly: disable_email
  = f.text_area  :description, rows: 5
....
```

Comment: Disabling the form field in your page, as @razevans suggests, looks like the right answer to me. But you also need to prevent any values being accepted when the query is received by your controller, in case you get naughty people trying to hack your site. Best way is to use strong parameters and not include this field in the list.